# Add typo3 coding guide lines to php sniffer

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript, phpsniff

I am trying to add typo3 coding guide lines for one my project .What i have done is http://forge.typo3.org/projects/team-php_codesniffer/wiki/Using_the_TYPO3_Coding_Standard. Cloned the GIT repository into my local repository and copy/pasted the folders TYPO3 and TYPO3v4 to /opt/lampp/htdocs/PHP_CodeSniffer/CodeSniffer/Standards . and when i tried this command in console ""/opt/lampp/bin/phpcs  -i" 'TYPO3 & TYPO3v4' are not showing as installed standards ??

"/opt/lampp/bin/phpcs --standard=TYPO3 index.php 
ERROR: the "TYPO3" coding standard is not installed. The installed coding standards are PSR2, PHPCS, PSR1, Zend, PEAR, Squiz and MySource
"

Comment: ok i have fixed it by myself . This installation path was wrong

Comment: please close the question